# How to slide images in div up and down with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

html code

```
<div class="up_arrow"></div>
<div class="content">
    <img src="image_one">
    <img src="image_two">
    <img src="image_three">
</div>
<div class="down_arrow"></div>
```

Here "image_two" and "image_three" are hidden. What I want is, when I click on "down_arrow" div, "image_one" changes to "image_two" and again when I click on "down_arrow" div, "image_two" changes to "image_three".

Similarly for "up_arrow", image changes from "image_three" to "image_two" just like an image slider. Does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: I know, like many other users of SO. What have you tried? What is the problem?

Comment: I tried jquery toggle function . But it didn't work.

Comment: `toggle` event method was deprecated and removed from jQuery. Can you show your attempt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could animate the `scrollTop` property of the `.content` element

```
var gallery = $('.content'),
    height = gallery.height();

$('.arrow').on('click', function(){
    var up = $(this).is('.up_arrow');

    if (up) {
        gallery.animate({'scrollTop': '-=' + height});
    } else {
        gallery.animate({'scrollTop': '+=' + height});        
    }
});
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/a2xmr1mn/

---

**note**: i have added a common (*`arrow`*) class to the arrows for styling/targeting

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
$('div.up_arrow').on('click', function() {
    var $actImg = $(this).siblings('div.content').find('img:visible');
    if(!$actImg.is(':first-child')) {
        $actImg.hide();
        $actImg.prev().show();
    }
});
```

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5ovt2777/).

Answer (score 0):

For variety, just another approach:

```
$(".down_arrow").on("click", function ()
{
  var actImage = $("img:visible").index();
  var nextImage = (actImage + 1) < $("img").length ? actImage + 1 : 0;
  $("img:eq(" + actImage + ")").hide();
  $("img:eq(" + nextImage + ")").show();
});
$(".up_arrow").on("click", function ()
{
  var actImage = $("img:visible").index();
  var nextImage = actImage > 0 ? actImage - 1 : $("img").length - 1;
  $("img:eq(" + actImage + ")").hide();
  $("img:eq(" + nextImage + ")").show();
});
```

Not requested, but when the first image is displayed, click on `up_arrow` displays the last image; when the last image is displayed, click on `down_arrow` displays the first image.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bbx332sb/)