# Automatic change image up to down on time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need this code without clicking function. I need it with normal slideshow against time.

I mean image will change after 5 sec automatically.

```js
var gallery = $('.content'),
    height = gallery.height();

$('.arrow').on('click', function(){
    var up = $(this).is('.up_arrow');
    
    if (up) {
        gallery.animate({'scrollTop': '-=' + height});
    } else {
        gallery.animate({'scrollTop': '+=' + height});        
    }
});
```

```css
.content{
    width:400px;
    height:300px;
    overflow:hidden;
    border:1px solid #999;
}
.content img{display:block;}
.arrow{
    display:inline-block;
    padding:5px 15px;
    background:#eee;
    border-radius:3px;
    margin:3px 0;
    cursor:pointer;
    border:1px solid #ddd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="arrow up_arrow">UP</div>
<div class="content">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/400x300?text=image+1">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/400x300?text=image+2">
   <img src="http://placehold.it/400x300?text=image+3">
</div>
<div class="arrow down_arrow">DOWN</div>
```

Comment: I don't understand the question... if jQuery is loaded, the up and down buttons work.... ??

Comment: instead `$('.arrow').on()` use `$(document).ready()`

Comment: Use [`setInterval()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp)

Comment: @LinkinTED I don't want those two buttons. I just want that images will automatically slide up to down or down to up after 5sec interval for infinity

Comment: possible Dublicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27580389/how-to-slide-images-in-div-up-and-down-with-jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this?

```js
var gallery = $('.content'),
    height = gallery.height(),
    scrollHeight = gallery[0].scrollHeight,
    y = 0;

$(function() {
  setInterval(function() {
    y += height;
    if( y >= scrollHeight ) {
      y = 0;
    }
    gallery.animate({'scrollTop':  y });
  }, 2000);
});
```

```css
.content{
    width:400px;
    height:300px;
    overflow:hidden;
    border:1px solid #999;
}
.content img{display:block;}
.arrow{
    display:inline-block;
    padding:5px 15px;
    background:#eee;
    border-radius:3px;
    margin:3px 0;
    cursor:pointer;
    border:1px solid #ddd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="content">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/400x300?text=image+1">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/400x300?text=image+2">
   <img src="http://placehold.it/400x300?text=image+3">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Man.. This is it.

Answer (score 0):

View this example. Run with plunker

```js
// Add your javascript here
$(function(){
 var gallery = $('.content'),
  height = gallery.height();
  


  setInterval(function(){ 
 
 gallery.animate({'scrollTop': '+=' + height},1000,function(){
 gallery.animate({'scrollTop':0},0);
  gallery.append($('.content img:first'));
 }); 

   }, 5000);
   
   });
```

```css
/* Put your css in here */

h1 {
  color: red;
}

.content{
    width:400px;
    height:300px;
    overflow:hidden;
    border:1px solid #999;
}
.content img{display:block;}
.arrow{
    display:inline-block;
    padding:5px 15px;
    background:#eee;
    border-radius:3px;
    margin:3px 0;
    cursor:pointer;
    border:1px solid #ddd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title><!-- Title here --></title>
    <link data-require="jqueryui" data-semver="1.10.0" rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.0/css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.10.0.custom.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="jquery" data-semver="3.0.0" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.js"></script>
    <script data-require="jqueryui" data-semver="1.10.0" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
<div class="content">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/400x300?text=image+1">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/400x300?text=image+2">
   <img src="http://placehold.it/400x300?text=image+3">
</div>
  </body>

</html>
```